# vsftpd - add a user with restriction to home directory without ssh access

Tags: vsftpd

I need to add a new user on my Ubuntu 18.04 server that can't login on a SSH terminal but has limited SFTP access to his home directory.

Here's what I did:
1. I added the following line to /etc/passwd:

```
my_ftp:x:1001:1001::/var/www/html/specific_folder:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

2. I added the following lines to /etc/vsftpd.conf:

   chroot_local_user=YES

   chroot_list_enable=YES

According to what I found out this should do the job. However, with this configuration the user can't login via FTP at all. When I change the shell to bash the FTP access works but with /etc as starting directory.

EDIT: My main user works just fine over vsftpd, with the correct starting directory.

Comment: Your shell `/usr/sbin/nologin` should be listed in the `/etc/shells` file. Is it there?

Comment: It wasn't but for the nologin this shouldn't be necessary, should it?  Anyway I just tried it and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes, in most of distributions it is required to add `/usr/sbin/nologin` to `/etc/shells`, to user using this shell can ftp to a server. More questions. 1) You specified that you added a line to `/etc/passwd` file; I hope you added the user properly, but not just simply added that specific line to the file? 2) What is an error in logs when you try to ftp? 3) The user home directory (and path to it), does it have enough permissions for that user?

Comment: 1. Yes, I added the user with a sudo command and then edited etc/passwd in order to change their shell path. 2. This is written to the ssh log: Feb  6 15:13:02 myserver sshd[31161]: User my_ftp not allowed because shell /sbin/nologin does not exist
Feb  6 15:13:02 myserver sshd[31161]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=00.00.00.00  user=$
Feb  6 15:13:05 myserver sshd[31161]: Failed password for invalid user my_ftp from 00.00.00.00 port 20981 ssh2
3. Yes, with the user granted shell access the directory is accessible.

Comment: I can see `/usr/sbin/nologin` used in `/etc/passwd` and `/sbin/nologin` in logs. In many systems /sbin is symlink to `/usr/sbin`, I do not have Ubuntu right here to check. I would try to add both `/sbin/nologin` and `/usr/sbin/nologin`  to `/etc/shells` to avoid related troubles.

Comment: I just added /usr/sbin/nologin to /etc/shells. No change unfortunately.

Comment: I remember you already added  `/usr/sbin/nologin` to `/etc/passwd` before, and now you had in logs complains regarding `/sbin/nologin`. And now you added `/usr/sbin/nologin` again? What about `/sbin/nologin`? Sorry, I'm confused now.

Comment: I added both paths to be sure.